# Workflow Rule - Only if created by specific object

Tags: workflow

Is it possible to create a workflow rule that only triggers upon creation/edit of an object if that object was created due to a specific object or another workflow rule?

Basically, I have an object Intakes that has a rule that sets the name field. When Intakes is created, it also creates a record in the Leads object. I want to create a rule that sets the name of the created Leads record only if that record were created from the Intakes object/workflow rule.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Just to be clear do you mean that every time a record is created under the Intake object a record will be created under Lead object corresponding to that?

Comment: No - I already have a workflow that creates a lead when an intake is created. What I want to do is create another workflow that names the lead, but I only want to run that workflow if that lead was created by an intake.  We will have leads from both, people and companies. Company leads will come from the intake object, and I don't want the workflow to name leads to overwrite the name of leads we will have for people. Hope that is more clear!

Comment: What method are you using to create a Lead when an Intake is created?  Could you just name the Lead when you create it from Intake?

Comment: No, I don't think that what you are trying to achieve is possible at least using two separate workflows and all @AlexisFrisch rather I will advise you that if you are creating a Lead then why not name it too at the same time.

Comment: Ah, so you're suggesting using one workflow to create a lead and also name it? That way, those created by that workflow would only be named at that time, and it shouldn't affect leads created by other means?

Comment: Yes, you got it right @AlexisFrisch

Comment: Awesome - Thanks!